# which log files can be deleted in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, error-log

My hard drive is filling up. Is it safe to delete SQL Server dump files and error log files? It looks like files in multiple folders can be deleted.

Following are the paths where the log and dump files growing, Is it ok to delete these files to free up space? The dump folder has over 30gb.

Log File Location:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\Polybase\dump

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\Polybase

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the Transaction Logs are important because they are for database recovery, by keeping track of all transactions that occur. Transaction Logs allow you to recover your database to any point in time (within the granularity of how often you backup the Transaction Logs).

If your Transaction Logs are eating up your disk space, you may not be backing them up frequently enough (or at all, as some people don't realize they need to be backed up). A backup marks the Transaction Log file for reuse, so it won't continue growing.

If your database doesn't need granular level point in time recovery, and you're willing to lose data as much as your last Full or Differential Backup, then you can switch your database's [Recovery Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to Simple Recovery Model. This will allow the Transaction Log to automatically be overwritten as soon as any active transactions are committed. That way the Transaction Log will re-use the space it has allocated already, minimizing any Transaction Log growth.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want clean the Error logs and Polybase dump, but before cleaning up try to check why they growing up and fix it, otherwise no matter the number of times you clean, it grow again!

1. **Polybase Dumps:** You might have installed knowingly/unknowingly all features of SQL Server, and Polybase is one of them, pls follow [these steps](https://nielsberglund.com/2019/11/20/fix-polybase-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/) to fix the Polybase dumps creation issue
2. **SQL-Error-Log:** It's always best practice to [cycle-error-log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which you can automate with following configuration (via SSMS)

[image]

15 is suitable number in my environment, you can set the number as per your requirement

[image]